# Document containing array not getting inserted into mongodb using mongoose and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

@ Norman .. thank you for reply....I am trying hard to know my error.. My code goes link this:

''''

```
  const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
    const Customer = require('../models/custdetails');
    const async    = require('async');
```

''''

Then I have some code related to sanitization .. then customer object is created

''''

```
const customer = new Customer({
  firm_name : req.body.firm_name,
  firm_feature : req.body.firm_feature,
  first_name: req.body.first_name,
  last_name: req.body.last_name,
  mob_no: req.body.mob_no,
  cust_email : req.body.cust_email,
  date_of_onboard: req.body.date_of_onboard,
  date_of_visit: req.body.date_of_visit,
  cust_need : req.body.cust_need,
  status : req.body.status,
  contact_back : req.body.contact_back,
});
```

''''

here firm feature and cust_need are both arrays, then

''''

```
const data = req.body;
customer.update({$push: {customer: data},function(err, res){if (err) {
          console.log("This is the error while inserting data:", err);
          }else {console.log(res); }   }   });

          res.redirect(customer.url);
        }
]
```

''''

My data is not getting inserted into database. I have tried every method. Please help

I have also tried as below

```
''''

    (async function(){
          try {
            const filter = { first_name: req.body.first_name};
            const options = {upsert: true};  
            const result = await customer.updateOne(filter, {$set:{data}}, options).then(function(){
            console.log("data is inserted");
            console.log('${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)')
          })
           }catch(err) {
            console.log("Some error has occurred in insertion");
            console.log(err);
          };
        });
        res.status(200).redirect(customer.url);
      }
```

''''

Below is my custdetails.js

''''

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CustSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firm_name:{type: String, maxLength:50},
    firm_feature: {type : { type: String }, enum: ['Private Limited Company', 'Public Limited Company',
                                      'Partnerships Company', 'Limited Liability Partnership LLP',
                                      'One Person Company', 'Sole Proprietorship',
                                      'Section 8 Company']},
    first_name: {type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100},
    last_name: {type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100},
    mob_no: {type: Number, required: true, maxLength:10},
    cust_email:{type: String, lowercase: true}, //always converts emailto lowercase before saving
    date_of_onboard: {type: Date},
    date_of_visit: {type: Date},
    cust_need: {type : { type: String }, enum:['Four Wheeler Loan', 'Home Loan', 'Two Wheeler Loan']},
    brperson: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Branch'},
    status: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CustInstance'},
    contact_back: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CustInstance' },

  }
);

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustSchema);
```

''''

Comment: When asking a question it is expected you will show some code so it is easier to help you.  For example when using mongoose you might have a node file for the your data model/schema (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). That would be a good file to share.

Comment: Put a your code in a code block. Can you please add the code of the "custdetails.js" file. Just want to see the definition of the array. Like:
```comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],```

Comment: @ norman...took me some time to understand how to post reply..i was writing in comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert I would switch to "**customer.save()**" method. Here is an example from my code:

```js
customer.save((err) => {
  if (err) { return next(err); }

  // Respond to request indicating the user was created
  res.status(201).json({ customer: customer }).end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...but the code is creating a new document without array fields getting inserted. even {upsertdated: true} is used in updateOne...them also I am unable to insert all fields. Insertmany also not working with mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I could save data without array fields getting added, using .save as suggested by Norman and then I $pushed array into the same document by using findOneAndUpdate. I was thinking I could write full data including array fields in one go into the document, but that did not happen...Is this the only answer if I am using node.js, express, mongoose and mongodb?..I dont know. The code goes like this

//First save data without array fields getting saved

```
 customer.save((err) => {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                } );
```

//then save array fields

const filter = { first_name: req.body.first_name};
const options = {upsert: true};

```
      Customer.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {$push: {firm_feature: req.body.firm_feature, cust_need: req.body.cust_need}}, options).then (function(err,res) {
          if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }else {
          console.log("docs inserted");

        }
      });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).